# accessing repeated properties in jinja2 template on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm fairly new to GAE (in python) and haven't quite been able to figure out how to do this from the docs or google searches:

I'm trying to access the first value in a repeated string property in a jinja template.

I'm using Google's User class from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User created like so:

```
user_data = self.user_model.create_user(user_name,
        unique_properties,
        email_address=email, name=name, password_raw=password,
        last_name=last_name, verified=False)
```

From what I can tell from the source, it seems the user_name is stored in auth_ids[0] in the google implementation.

In the template I'd like to display the username, in a Post, which has a User key property:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):

    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    author = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
```

I'm trying to do this in the template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class='post'>
{{ post.content }} <br />
{{ post.author.auth_ids[0] }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It works for content, but not username, I've tried several different alternatives, any pointers would be extremely useful!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with repeated properties. Neither content nor author are repeated, but author is a Key which is effectively a reference to a different model.

Comment: you're right! I can't figure out how to change the title... :(

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha!

I've discovered that you can add 'get' into the template in order to access properties:

I added a username property to the model:

```
@property
def username(self):
    return self.auth_ids[0]
```

Then accessed it via 'get':

```
{{ post.author.get.username }}
```

So simple when you know how! ;)